# Which maven settings.xml file will sudo use?

Tags: maven, unix

I have a shell script which runs a maven build task. When the script is run, it is run as the sudo user. However, I am behind a proxy and therefore need to specify proxy details inside my ~/.m2/settings.xml file. This is currently in the main user's home directory.

What I've found is that when this script is run as sudo, it's not picking up the settings.xml file from the other user's ~/.m2/settings.xml file.

How can I specify these settings for the sudo/root user? Should I just put this settings.xml inside the root user's home directory as well?

Answer (score 6):

When you use sudo, I think `user.home` property changes and that is why this,

You can explicitly specify settings file by

```
 -s
```

for example

```
mvn clean compile -s /home/foo/.m2/settings.xml
```

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't pass in the settings file because the maven call is referenced inside a shell script which I really shouldn't change :(

Comment: write a minimal java code that prints `user.home` property and launch that using sudo and see, and just create soft link to that directory for your settings.xml

Answer (score 6):

If all users on the machine will always need the proxy settings you can simply add them to the global [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file.

This can normally be found at `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`.